# How to create hierarchical tree of a json variable that shows names and toggles for show/hide?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

What is the easiest way to create hierarchical tree that displays a json variable with names and toggle option? 
The end result should be similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: With recursion :)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `three.js`? How is your data represented? (Please don't refer to images, just provide it in text).